# Oracle - != and <> in a query producing different results

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So I have a table that looks like this:

```
NAME      COMP_DATE

Joe       1/25/2022 4:59:59.837000 pm
Steve     1/31/2022 12:15:45.234224 PM 
James     1/15/2022 3:15:45.5434000  PM
Austin    1/17/2022 2.15.14.334000 PM
```

Now here is the thing ...I have a query that looks like this .

```
Select * from Table where comp_date != sysdate - 10.
```

I was expecting the results to include joe, steve , james..and for some reason Joe is not coming through.

However when I change this query to look like this

```
Select * from Table where comp_date <> sysdate - 10.
```

I am getting all the right results.

I don't understand why that would be ?   Whats the difference between != and <>

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; and the `INSERT` statement for your sample data; and the date and time (and time zone) at which you ran the query so that we can replicate your output. At the moment, your output is not replicable [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5775ac03e71b0472a18ea6fda1760887) and there should be no difference between the two operators.

Comment: You should put in the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements, but for "Joe" the "pm" is lowercase (and for James there seems an extra space before the PM). If this is just text data rather than a TIMESTAMP datatype then you should put an explicit TO_DATE

Comment: @GaryMyers `TO_TIMESTAMP` would be needed, `TO_DATE` will fail with the fractional seconds.

Comment: Lot of *suspective* points there - the last timestamp looks more like a *misspelled* IP address...

Comment: @MT0 You can ignore the extra precision - for example to_date('12-jan 2021 13:32:44.001','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss#####')

Answer (score 2):

[Explain Plan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/4808122) is your helper in such cases of doubt.

It shows in the *Predicate Information* block the exact *predicate* that Oracle uses.

Here the results for your two queries limited to the predicate information

**For <>**

```
EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'neq' into   plan_table  FOR
select * from table_name where comp_date <> sysdate -10;

SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY('plan_table', 'neq','ALL'));

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter("COMP_DATE"<>SYSDATE@!-10)
```

**For !=**

```
EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'neq' into   plan_table  FOR
select * from table_name where comp_date != sysdate -10;

     
SELECT * FROM table(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY('plan_table', 'neq','ALL'));

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter("COMP_DATE"<>SYSDATE@!-10)
```

What you can *clearly* see it that Oracle uses only the `<>` operator internally.

So no difference is *expected*.

Despite this exercise, you may also make a **thought experiment** only.

You know that `sysdate` is of a `DATE` data type , i.e. **without second precision**. Your *timestamps* have second precision.

So a *not equal* comparison will  always be true. Compare a `TIMESTAMP` with a `DATE` conveverst the `DATE` in a `TIMESTAMP` (without second precision) as you can see in the example

```
EXPLAIN PLAN  SET STATEMENT_ID = 'neq' into   plan_table  FOR
select * from table_name where comp_date != to_date('2022-01-25 16:59:59','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') - 10;

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   1 - filter("COMP_DATE"<>TIMESTAMP' 2022-01-15 16:59:59')
```

So recheck your setup and try to repaet the result. Maybe the cause it as trivial as that the table was not filled at the time of the check, comp_date was `NULL` etc.

Comment: "So a not equal comparison will always be true." This is not always the case. If the timestamp value has a fractional seconds value of zero then it is possible for a timestamp and a date to be equal and then the not equal comparison will be false. In the case of the OP's data, a not equals comparison will be true for all rows (since they all have non-zero fractional seconds) but for the general case you cannot make that statement.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my *oversimplification* @MT0, the claim is related to the presented data (if this could be considered as a valid input). Of course more important the comparison will fail if the timestamp will be `NULL` this all was intentionaly omitted to keep the answer in a reasonable size.

Answer (score 1):

> Whats the difference between != and <>

There is no difference; the `!=`, `^=` and `<>` operators are [functionally equivalent](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Comparison-Conditions.html#GUID-828576BF-E606-4EA6-B94B-BFF48B67F927).

If you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (NAME, COMP_DATE) AS
SELECT 'Joe',    TIMESTAMP '2022-01-25 16:59:59.837000' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Steve',  TIMESTAMP '2022-01-31 12:15:45.234224' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'James',  TIMESTAMP '2022-01-15 15:15:45.543400' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Austin', TIMESTAMP '2022-01-17 14:15:14.334000' FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
Select * from Table_name where comp_date != TIMESTAMP '2022-02-04 16:59:59.837000' - 10.
```

And:

```sql
Select * from Table_name where comp_date <> TIMESTAMP '2022-02-04 16:59:59.837000' - 10.
```

Both output all 4 rows. This is because `TIMESTAMP - NUMBER` is not a valid operation but `DATE - INTEGER` is a valid operation so the `TIMESTAMP` is implicitly cast to a `DATE` and the fractional seconds component is lost and the values are not equal.

The query is effectively:

```sql
Select *
from   Table_name
where  comp_date <> CAST(
                      CAST(
                        TIMESTAMP '2022-02-04 16:59:59.837000'
                        AS DATE
                      )
                      - 10.
                      AS TIMESTAMP
                    )
```

But if you subtract an interval data type rather than a number:

```sql
Select *
from   Table_name
where  comp_date != TIMESTAMP '2022-02-04 16:59:59.837000' - INTERVAL '10' DAY
```

and

```sql
Select *
from   Table_name
where  comp_date <> TIMESTAMP '2022-02-04 16:59:59.837000' - INTERVAL '10' DAY
```

Then both queries return the rows:

> | NAME | COMP_DATE |
> | --- | --- |
> | Steve | 2022-01-31 12:15:45.234224000 |
> | James | 2022-01-15 15:15:45.543400000 |
> | Austin | 2022-01-17 14:15:14.334000000 |

There is no difference in the two queries.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=96cad42d874d2c7c5a46f6cdfb20d207)*

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no difference between `!=` and `<>`, there are rare cases where changing *any* character in a query can cause problems.

Check the execution plan for both queries and pay special attention to the "Note" section. It's possible that only one of your queries has a plan management feature that is influencing the execution plan. If the plans are different, one of them will probably have something like this in the Note section:

```
Note
-----
   - SQL profile "PROFILE_TEST" used for this statement
```

A different execution plan *shouldn't* ever cause different results. But maybe only one of your execution plans is running into a wrong-results bug or is using a corrupt index or table.

This is a one-in-a-million scenario. So it's more likely that there's a logical mistake somewhere in the query.